# how to plot confusion matrix and classification report?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, confusion-matrix, multiclass-classification

How can I plot the confusion matrix and classification report if I don't have y_test?

I spleted my data like this:

```
train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
test_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

Comment: are you working with a no supervised learning problem?

Comment: no i am working with CNN image classification

Comment: try to itera in test_ds and print the result. In general you will have the image rgb data and the label for that image. I hitnk the will come as one-hot vector. like this [0,0,1,0] where the class value is the index of 1 value.